# Вопрос по мультипоточному программированию

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вопрос следующий. Предположим есть у меня класс А, который работает с несколькими потоками. В конструкторе класса А я создаю экземпляр другого класса В.

Экземпляры класса В для каждого потока будут индивидуальны?

Приведу для примера такой код:

```
public class EmployeeService implements Service<Employee> {
  private Dao<Employee> employeeDao;
  private Dao<Phone> phoneDao;
  private static ThreadLocal<Connection> connectionTL = new ThreadLocal<>();

  private void initTransaction() {
    try {
        connectionTL.set(pool.getConnection());//коннекшн берется из пула соединений
    } catch (PoolException e) {
        throw new ServiceException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void editEmployee(Employee obj) {
    initTransaction();
    Connection connection = connectionTL.get();
    //по логике в этом месте data race не должно быть ибо для каждого потока будет свой экземпляр дао.
    //и коннекшины не должны перетерться
    employeeDao.setConnection(connection); //проставляю connections для DAO слоя
    phoneDao.setConnection(connection);

    ...Логика вызова методов класса B
  }

  public class AbstractDao<T> implements DAO<T>{
    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public T edit(T obj) throws DaoException {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement =        connection.prepareStatement(getSqlStringEdit())) {

            ... логика запросов к БД

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DaoException(e);
        }
        return newObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет. Взаимоотношения между объектами определяются ссылками друг на друга в памяти. Имея ссылку, любой поток может обращаться к методам объекта. То, о чём вы пишите, это singleton-per-thread&nbsp;&mdash; паттерн Одиночка, который создает один экземпляр на поток. Это нужно организовывать собственными силами.

Comment: То есть я правильно понял, что, если я в методах класса А сначала проставляю какие либо значения нестатическим полям класса В, а потом, в том же методе вызваю метод класса В который работает с этим полем, то Data Race по идее быть не должно?

Comment: В этом коде может быть состояние гонки. При выполнении `editEmployee` подключение (connection) будет уникальным для каждого потока. Но `employeeDao` и `phoneDao` одни и те же во всех экземплярах класса `EmployeeService`. Если `editEmployee` будет запущен из разных потоков, то в `employeeDao` будет записано одно подключение, затем другое (вторым потоком). При этом первый поток будет туда писать, ни о чём не подозревая.

Comment: Но  из моего вопроса и Вашего первого ответа следует, что если я создаю в конструкторе `EmployeeService`  экземпляры класса `EmployeeDao`
`public EmployeeService() {
        employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
    }` то для каждого потока будет создан свой экземпляр `EmployeeDAO` и писать они по идее должны даже не знаю друг об друге. То есть один поток устанавливает соединение(`connection`) в свой экземпляр, другой в свой.

Comment: Я в вашем коде вижу, что `ThreadLocal` объявлен только Connection. `EmployeeDao` не thread local, и всего один экземпляр на `EmployeeService`.